# How to cycle through an array of values to optimize number of calls to a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, performance, google-sheets

I have an array of rows from a Google Spreadsheet interspersed with numbers between the bounds of 1 and 800:

```
var rowPositions = [1,3,4,5,9,10,11,12...795,799,800]
```

And, for efficiency's sake, I need to make an API call to the function deleteRows, which accepts two parameters:

```
deleteRows(positionOfFirstRow, howManyRowsShouldBeDeletedStartingFromFirstRow)
```

[Google Documentation for deleteRows.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleterowsrowposition-howmany)

How can I create a function in Javascript that calls deleteRows a minimal number of times for a given array? IE, using the aforementioned array as an example, the function calls deleteRows to remove the row at position 1, then calls it again to delete 3,4,5, then again to delete 10,11,12, etc...?

In other words, how can I transform that rowPositions array into a two-dimensional one, ex.:

```
var 2DrowPositions = [[1,1],[3,2],[5,1],[9,4]]
```

which I can then use to call the deleteRows function once per provided coordinate.

Comment: Yes, I believe so. @DavidThomas

Comment: Bear in mind I did post invalid JavaScript, it should’ve been: `[[1,1],[3,3]]`. My bad. I’d suggest thinking through the end result you want, and posting the desired outcome in your question, as well as your understanding of how to use your solution; that way people are more likely to understand how to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are given an array of items to delete like `[1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 15, 18, 19, 20, 23]` you can step through that array and look for consecutive numbers. Keep track of how many consecutive numbers you see and when you hit a non-consecutive number, save the old one and start again.

Here's one way to do that, which is reasonably easy to read:

```js
let del = [1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 15, 18, 19, 20, 23]

let res = []
let curr = {start: del[0], count: 0}
del.forEach((item, i, arr) => {
    if (i === 0 || arr[i] === 1 + arr[i-1]) curr.count++
    else {
        res.push(curr)
        curr = {start: arr[i], count:1}
    }
})
res.push(curr)
console.log(res)
```

This will return an array of objects of the form `{start, count}` which you can use in your function with something like:

```
res.forEach(r => deleteRows(r.start, r.count))
```